# How to create new target in AppCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, target, appcode

In XCode its very easy to create new target and add build script, but in AppCode I can not find these two options.

So, is there any way to add new target and build script in AppCode?

Comment: You can open your AppCode project in XCode and add a new target, then use it in AppCode.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, thank you. Please, rewrite your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: done! But hopefully they'll provide the ability in the very near future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to this thread (from 2012)](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/435190;jsessionid=BBD0E569DF81D34874A7DD6B59D69FA2?tstart=-2), you can modify the target for files but not create or delete targets.